# How to put a direct download link at my website for My YouTube channel videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, vimeo, vimeo-api, dailymotion-api

At my website, I am using the thumbnails of the videos listed at my YouTube channel. So the users of my website can click on the thumbnails and video start download automatically from YouTube channel. I tried many softwares and copied their download link and put to my website but after sometime the link didn't worked at all, may be because YouTube change some parameters in the URL.

So is there any way to offer one click direct download from YouTube, or any other like Vimeo, dailymotion,etc. I tried already the vimeo and I am able to get the direct download but the same problem as the url doesn't work after sometime on other ip, so my users are not able to download and they redirect to vimeo website.

I will appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

With YouTube it's **absolutely not possible** via the official API. There are certain third-party scripts in existence that may be able to download videos off YouTube anyways (cf. e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198185/how-to-download-youtube-video-in-java)) **but be advised that this is against the YouTube terms of service** and thus illegal.

With Vimeo it's a little bit different, to my understanding. Video owners can opt to allow users to download their videos, but I think this is only through the player. Vimeo won't provide you with a download link, with [this exception](https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:30952).

This is not what these services were designed for anyways. They are social media platforms, not video hosters.